# Gensim: Unable to train the LDA model

Tags: nlp, gensim, lda, corpus

I have a list of sentences, and I follow the instructions at the [tutorial](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/tut1.html) to make a corpora from it:

```
texts = [[word for word in document.lower().split() if word.isalpha()] for document in documents]
corpus = corpora.Dictionary(texts)
```

I want to train a LDA model on this corpora and extract the topics keywords.

```
lda = models.LdaModel(corpus, num_topics=10)
```

However, I receive an error while training: `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`. What am I doing wrong? What the format of a corpus should be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After making a corpora you should make a single corpus with `doc2bow` which makes hashes from words (so-called ['hashing trick'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_hashing)):

```
texts = [[word for word in document.lower().split() if word.isalpha()] for document in documents]
corpus = corpora.Dictionary(texts)
hashed_corpus = [corpora.doc2bow(text) for text in texts]
```

And after that you can train your model with `hashed_corpus`:

```
lda = models.LdaModel(corpus, id2word=corpus, num_topics=5)
```

`id2word` maps your topics from hashes to words, and using of it makes it possible to get topics as words, not numbers.